# Gradle - Execution failed for task 'sonarAnalyze' - java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: build, gradle, sonarqube

I have this error when running sonar with my gradle build script.

gradle  sonarAnalyze

```
15:41:02.931 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an   exception.
15:41:02.931 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
15:41:02.931 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
15:41:02.931 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task  ':sonarAnalyze'.
15:41:02.934 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String



 My sonar 

sonar {
        server { 
        url = "http://server.com:9000"
        }
        database {

            url="jdbc:mysql://server:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8"
            driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            username="sonar"
            password="sonar"
                }
                project {
                    coberturaReportPath=file("$buildDir/reports/cobertura/coverage.xml")
                    language = "java"
                }

            }
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Thanks. I will do exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

What version of Sonar are you running?  I was having this problem when running Sonar 4.1.1 because I was using the same [Gradle Sonar plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/sonar_plugin.html) that you are.  I switched to the [Gradle Sonar Runner plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/sonar_runner_plugin.html), and the problem was resolved.